# AngularJs and bootstrap css

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use AngularJS and Bootstrap css, by following the below example link:
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/angularjs/angularjs-form-with-bootstrap . I have followed the same UI. However, I have few additional controls such as Datetimepicker for Bootstrap 3 * version : 4.15.35 - Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker, so which will 4 controls in one row -

label datepicker label timepicker

How should the UI  and CSS be defined 4 controls in row?

Also, if using ng-repeat -what is the css to be used? 
Adding existing code:

```
<body class="ng-cloak">
    <div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
        <form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate="" >


            <div class="container form-horizontal" ng-show="createMenu">
                <br />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Season<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select name="seasonTypeSelect" required="" ng-model="selectedSeasonType" class="dropdown form-control cl-sm-6" ng-options="season.SeasonTypeName for season in seasons" ng-change="updateImageUrl(selectedSeasonType)">
                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <span class="error" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.seasonTypeSelect.$error.required">Please select season.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control" required="" ng-model="nName" id="nName" name="nName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <span class="error" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.nName.$error.required">Please enter Name.</span>
                    </div>                    
                </div>

              </form>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to add a ng-repeat, which has label, textbox, textarea, delete icon in one row.
I also want to add the Eonasdan datetime picker, which has label, date control, label time control in one row.

How should the above be aligned ?

Comment: what do you have so far? please add code

Comment: I have added the existing code. I  want to add a ng-repeat, which has label, textbox, textarea, delete icon in one row. I also want to add the Eonasdan datetime picker, which has label, date control, label,  time control in one row.

Comment: might i suggest [angular-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)